# Taking power from a single pole switch

Tags: wiring

I have a 2-gang box with a single pole switch and i took power from there to a dimmer next to it. Can i take power a second time from the original switch to install another switch?

Comment: Maybe. We would need to see what is going on inside the switch box.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box? Also, what is this new switch feeding?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the circuit is not overloaded. For residential  there is no limit to the number of devices by the NEC so you can add,  but your total load needs to be at 80% of the circuit to prevent overloading. 
The one limit you may run into is box fill where the number of wires devices is limited.

Comment: Use pigtails, not the backstab.